# Sorting &Pagination for html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Am using this Json to Html table and am getting the values also. All I need to do is implement sorting for this. Can someone help me out?
where in the objArray am passing my Json data.
All I need to do is implement Sorting and pagination. Please help me out.

```
function CreateTableViewX(objArray, theme, enableHeader) {
        // set optional theme parameter
        if (theme === undefined) {
            theme = 'mediumTable'; //default theme
        }

        if (enableHeader === undefined) {
            enableHeader = true; //default enable headers
        }

        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

        var str = '<table class="' + theme + '">';

        // table head
        if (enableHeader) {
            str += '<thead><tr>';
            for (var index in array[0]) {
                str += '<th scope="col">' + index + '</th>';
            }
            str += '</tr></thead>';
        }

        // table body
        str += '<tbody>';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            str += (i % 2 == 0) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>';
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                str += '<td>' + array[i][index] + '</td>';
            }
            str += '</tr>';
        }
        str += '</tbody>'
        str += '</table>';
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Jquery [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/)

All you need is to refer Jquery and datables Script files in your solution, select your html table using an Id or class name and Initialize it like this.  Datatable will then take care of sorting and pagination for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tableID').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot :) but is there any way I could write the sorting method in my current script itself?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?, I would strongly suggest you to try out this plugin.